# Website to image

Tags: python, image, python-3.x

I'm running Python 3.1 and you would call me an advanced novice :)

My question is simple: I'm trying to make a simple program which asks the users for a URL (or multiple URLs) and then goes to the website and takes a screenshot (of the whole page, not just what can be seen in the browser without scrolling all the way down).

It's simpler then it sounds, I want to use an existing platform on the web, similar to this:

```
import subprocess
MYFILENAME = "google_screen"
MYURL = "www.google.com"
subprocess.Popen(['wget', '-O', MYFILENAME+'.png', 'http://images.websnapr.com/?url='+MYURL+'&size=s&nocache=82']).wait()
```

Although this website does not work :(, I'm wondering is it possible to do it with [this website](http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-web-to-image) and if so, how? If it is not possible, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a package called webkit2png that you can use for this, its located: [here](https://github.com/paulhammond/webkit2png/)

More information on [this blog post](http://rolandtapken.de/blog/2008-12/create-screenshots-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit)

Example from blog post(copied to SO for preservation, read the blog post to understand it if you have issues):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import signal

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt 4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage

def onLoadFinished(result):
    if not result:
        print "Request failed"
        sys.exit(1)

    # Set the size of the (virtual) browser window
    webpage.setViewportSize(webpage.mainFrame().contentsSize())

    # Paint this frame into an image
    image = QImage(webpage.viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    painter = QPainter(image)
    webpage.mainFrame().render(painter)
    painter.end()
    image.save("output2.png")
    sys.exit(0)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

webpage = QWebPage()
webpage.connect(webpage, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), onLoadFinished)
webpage.mainFrame().load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Edit: [Link to the pyqt4 download page](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the error `    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore`.  I have installed "webkit2png.py" into python31/lib is that right? do i need anything else?  O and thanks soooo much for the response

Comment: You probably don't have the pyqt4 packages installed here is a link for that : http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download  (and adding to answer for first time people who skip comments)

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know how to edit how long it waits for flash to load, e.g. SIGNAL("LoadFinished(bool)").  I'm trying to load google finance but I think it thinks the flash is still loading, while its just being constently editied.  thx

Comment: blog post link is dead

Comment: link updated to the blog author's new location, thanks @Jabberwockey!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium to get a screenshot, but it'll only be what is viewed by the browser.